# Shell script that runs two process that always update and never end in parallel

Tags: shell

I have two processes that I want to run forever but I want to continue using the same shell script to do commands while they're still running.

I've tried using forever but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

```
npm install forever -g

forever start scripts/node1_start.sh
forever start scripts/node2_start.sh
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just submit them to the background with &. `scripts/node1_start.sh &` will return immediately leaving node1 as a background process. Then you can do the same for `node2_start.sh`

Comment: I've tried this but since my process never ends and keeps updating console, it never goes to next line of shell code unless I Ctrl-C the current process

Answer (score 0):

As @rhubarbdog pointed out, running the **2** *external* shell scripts in the background will allow you to continue executing commands (unblocked) in the *current* script.

```
sh scripts/node1_start.sh &
sh scripts/node2_start.sh &

# Do commands here
```

Comment: This was the first way of implementing this but when I execute, it just stays on the first node1 start and since that script is only one command that never ends and updates every 0.5 seconds, it never goes to node2.